# Asus Q550L Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 update

Tags: windows-8, drivers, windows-8.1

I bought an Asus Q550L last week that came with Windows 8.1.  I thought it was already installed on the machine, but apparently it was just available for the update.  Anyway, I ran the Windows 8.1 update and it took a long time, but seemed successful.  Later in the evening the system told me I needed to update the WIFI adapter and two other items.  I ran them and once it installed and rebooted, it kept going to a screen that said "Please Wait" in the middle of the screen and "Cancel" at the bottom-right.  I let this set there for about a half hour before I forced the laptop to reboot.  Once it came up, it went right back to that screen.  I don't know what driver was causing that problem, but I couldn't get it to stop.  I decided to restore the system completely.  That worked okay, but of course I lost all my data.  The question is, how can I perform the Windows 8.1 update and get the right drivers to work?  The system also seemed a lot slower after the 8.1 update.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks :)

Comment: Repeat the process this time don't install the drivers in question

Comment: I'll can do that this go-round of course, but this tells me that I need updated drivers for handling Win 8.1.  Is there a more reliable location for obtaining drivers for the Asus Q550L system?  It is not listed on the Asus site I went to today.

Comment: Te best place to get the right drivers is the [official support page](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Q550LF&p=3&s=530).

Comment: Thanks! and31415 I was actually having trouble finding my model on Asus' support site.  Very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a little research on Microsofts website, my problem turned out to be a Windows 8.1 update issue.  The problem is that your Live account looses its mojo with Skydrive, etc.  The file that causes the window to popup and get stuck is "restoreoptin.exe".  You can kill the program when it pops up to gain access to your PC.

1. Press WinKey + r
2. Type taskkill /f /im restoreoptin.exe then Enter
3. The 'Please Wait' window should go away.

To fix the mojo between your PC and Skydrive, do this:

1. Go to Start, then activate the right side menu
2. Click the Change PC Settings near the bottom
3. Click Users
4. Click Disconnect under your username (This disconnects your login from your Live login and makes you create a local  login name)
5. After you create a new local user account, reboot (that's what I did)
6. Restart and login with the new account
7. Go back into the Change PC Setting/Users window
8. Click the "Switch to a Microsoft Account" and follow the instructions

This took care of my problem and I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Still new to this site.  Mojo is a reference to the Austin Powers movies.  Basically, I couldn't think of something good at the time to describe that the username was not syncing correctly with Microsoft, so I chose mojo. LOL

Comment: Not use slang, lot of users just do not understand it.

Comment: Whatever man :/